# how to remove 302 redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is happening with  only one page in my website. when I go to that page, it redirects back to home page of website.

here is the htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /course.php?name=$1&id=$2 [R=301,NC]
```

when I tried searching this problem on internet I found there is 302 temporary redirection.

please help in remove this problem.

Thanks!!

Comment: the htaccess rule does a 301 redirection, probably the page itself redirects and is not a htaccess issue, post the code of that page to see

Comment: if this page has a form in it (plausible) it does this as part pf the PRG pattern (POST-REDIRECT-GET) to avoid submiting the form twice, so there is an interplay here

Comment: this website is not allowing me to post the code (it is too long). also the page does not have any form. I think this may help - goo.gl/nnJzBp  I found this while searching for the solution. one more thing, I have not used any kind of redirection anywhere in the page